# How can I fix the count_words() function to create a proper linked list of words with their appropriate counts?

Tags: c, data-structures

Below is my **C** code, and my question is: why, in the `count_words` function, the `printf` for `word` and `(*wclist)->word` are the same for all but the first word added?

The `count_words` function is reading from a .txt file:

```
abc def aAa
bbb zzz aaa
```

Here is the code:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct word_count {
    char *word;
    int count;
    struct word_count *next;
};

typedef struct word_count WordCount; 

WordCount *word_counts = NULL;

/* The maximum length of each word in a file */
#define MAX_WORD_LEN 64


int count_words(WordCount **wclist, FILE *infile) {
    if (wclist == NULL || infile == NULL) { return 1; }

    char *word = malloc(sizeof *word * MAX_WORD_LEN + 1);
    if (!word) { return 1; }

    char c = fgetc(infile);
    while (c == ' ' || c == '\n') {
        c = fgetc(infile);
    }
    while (c != EOF) {
        while (!isalpha(c)) {
            if (c == EOF) {
                return 0;
            }
            c = fgetc(infile);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_WORD_LEN; ++i, c = fgetc(infile)) {
            if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == EOF) { 
                // THIS IS THE PORTION WHERE I AM CONFUSED ABOUT
                printf("%s\n%s\n%d\n%zd\n\n",
                       word, (*wclist)->word,
                       (*wclist)->count, len_words(*wclist));

                add_word(wclist, word);
                memset(word, 0, sizeof *word * MAX_WORD_LEN + 1);
                break; 
            }
            *(word + i) = tolower(c);
        }
        c = fgetc(infile);
    }
    return 0;
}      

int init_words(WordCount **wclist) {
    *wclist = calloc(1, sizeof(WordCount));
    if (*wclist == NULL) { return 1; }
    return 0;
}

ssize_t len_words(WordCount *wchead) {
    /* Return -1 if any errors are
       encountered in the body of
       this function.
    */
    if (wchead == NULL) { return -1; }
    if (wchead->word == NULL) { return 0; }

    ssize_t len = 1;
    WordCount *curr = wchead;
    while (curr->next != NULL) {
        len++;
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    return len;
}

WordCount *find_word(WordCount *wchead, char *word) {
    /* Return count for word, if it exists */
    WordCount *wc = wchead;
    while (wc != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(word, wc->word) == 0) { return wc; }
        wc = wc->next;
    }
    return NULL;
}

int add_word(WordCount **wclist, char *word) {
    /* If word is present in word_counts list, increment the count.
       Otherwise insert with count 1.
       Returns 0 if no errors are encountered in the body of
          this function; 1 otherwise.
    */
    if (wclist == NULL || word == NULL) { return 1; }

    if (len_words(*wclist) == 0) {
        (*wclist)->word = word;
        (*wclist)->count = 1;
        (*wclist)->next = NULL;
    } else {
        WordCount *found_word = find_word(*wclist, word);
        if (found_word == NULL) {
            WordCount *new = malloc(sizeof(WordCount));
            new->word = word;
            new->count = 1;
            new->next = NULL;

            WordCount *curr = *wclist;
            while (curr->next != NULL) {
                curr = curr->next;
            }
            curr->next = new;
        } else {
            found_word->count++;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    init_words(&word_counts);
    FILE *infile = fopen(argv[argc - 1], "r");
    count_words(&word_counts, infile);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem I am encountering is that the final result of the global variable `word_counts` has a null char pointer, a count of 6, and a `len_words(WordCount* wchead)` of 1.

I am expecting `count_words` to create a linked list of words in my .txt file with the appropriate counts for each word.

I know that my implementations for all the functions except for `count_words` is correct because I have individually tested them in my main function, but when I only use the `count_words` function in my `main` function the behavior I described above happens and I don't know why.

Comment: `add_word(wclist, word);` -> you have a single block of memory, allocated before the loop, which you keep overwriting. So all the pointers you store in the list point to the same memory block (which you overwrote with other contents after adding)

Comment: Christopher, this is pure C code, I don't know why you have added C++ tag! By the way using malloc() and memset() in C++ is considered bad practice.

Comment: Calling a function is not equivalent to testing it. Don't return error codes when you're going to leave them unchecked.

Comment: @UnholySheep But doesn't my add_word function grow the list? How should I fix it?

Comment: I regret to tell you that your code is thoroughly broken in more places than one, but the one that concerns you is easy to explain. Suppose you need to create a 100,000,000-long word list. Can you show where you allocate memory for 100,000,000 words?

Comment: @ChristopherTruong Consider `*wclist = calloc(1, sizeof(WordCount)); if (!wclist) { return 1; }`.. If `!wclist` is true, the the prior `*wclist` is like `*NULL`, which is undefined behavior.  I suspect you wanted `if (*wclist == NULL)`.

Comment: @n.m. I can fix that in the add_words function initially when len_words == 0 right? By setting (*wclist)->next to malloc(..) and the else block  with new->next = malloc(..).  Or else how would I know how much to allocate to the global variable storage initially?

Comment: @ChristopherTruong Tip;  Enable all compiler warnings. There are small things that distract from your larger goal.  Who knows, maybe its one of those small things.  Example of a side issue: why `size_t len = 1;` and not `ssize_t len = 1;`?  Mixing sign-ness of types leads to issues.  A well enabled compiler warns about this.  Use automated tools to quickly detect issues.  Is this _the_ issue? No, but it is like a distracting spelling grammar error.  Note that code that is warning free is better thought of.  Posted code has about 3 dozen warnings/errors.

Comment: Adding `#include <stdlib.h> #include <stdio.h> #include <string.h> #include <ctype.h>` brought the warning/error count down to about a dozen.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Thanks I'll fix that.  I have

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```
which I forgot to include here.

Comment: Minor: Not _the_ issue, yet `sizeof *word * MAX_WORD_LEN + 1` is conceptually wrong.  Should be `sizeof *word * (MAX_WORD_LEN + 1)`.  Also `MAX_WORD_LEN` definition missing.  Tip, try compiling exactly what is posted.

Comment: `*wclist` is not a word. Likewise `(*wclist)->next` is not a word. `(*wclist)->word` *points to* a word, and `(*wclist)->next->word` *points to* a word too, but the word itself is elsewhere. Where is it? How many of those are there?

Comment: @n.m. I fix this by using `strdup` in my `add_word(..)` function.  In `(*wclist)->word` and `new->word` I set it to `strdup(word)`.

Comment: Everything now works on my end after fixing to use `strdup(..)`!

Comment: "Everything now works" could be a little bit optimistic, there are various other errors, but yes, `strdup` fixes this one. I would *highly* recommend writing a function `char* get_word(FILE *f)` and using `strdup` insideit, it would simplify your code quite a bit. Bear in mind that `fgetc` returns `int` and not `char` for a reason amd you better understand that reason.

Comment: @n.m. I have changed `fgetc` variable to `int`, I don't exactly know why `fgetc` should return `int` - maybe because `char` is usually unsigned (not sure about this) and `EOF` is -1.  Why should you write `char *get_word(..)` function?

Comment: About fgetc: it is explained on this site many times, search. About get_word: just try it and see if your code becomes simpler.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in the code:

- in `count_words`, the variable `c` must be defined with type `int` for the end of file to be detected reliably.
- `word_counts` should just be initialized as an empty list, ie: a null pointer.  The sentinel you allocate `init_words(&word_counts)` is confusing.
- you should test and report failure to `fopen` the argument.  Furthermore, using `argv[0]` when no file argument was provided is unlikely to produce interesting output.
- there is a missing `(` in the `add_word` function:

  ```
    *wclist)->next = NULL;
  ```
- `find_word` will crash if the list is empty because you pass a null pointer to `strcmp` in `if (strcmp(word, wc->word) == 0)` for the first node.
- you always add the same `word` pointer to the list and clear its contents.  Since `add_word` does not allocate a copy of the word, all nodes point to the same buffer, which eventually contains an empty string, or transiently the last word read (as shown by the `printf` call).  Use `(*wclist)->word = strdup(word);` and `new->word = strdup(word);` in `add_word()`.

Here is a (heavily) modified version:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct WordCount WordCount;
struct WordCount {
    char *word;
    int count;
    struct WordCount *next;
};

#define MAX_WORD_LEN  100

void free_words(WordCount **wclist) {
    while (*wclist) {
        WordCount *wc = *wclist;
        *wclist = wc->next;
        free(wc->word);
        free(wc);
    }
}

size_t len_words(WordCount *wchead) {
    size_t length = 0;
    for (WordCount *wc = wchead; wc; wc = wc->next) {
        length++;
    }
    return length;
}

void list_words(WordCount *wchead) {
    for (WordCount *wc = wchead; wc; wc = wc->next) {
        printf("%s: %d\n", wc->word, wc->count);
    }
}

WordCount *find_word(WordCount *wchead, const char *word) {
    for (WordCount *wc = wchead; wc; wc = wc->next) {
        if (strcmp(word, wc->word) == 0) {
            return wc;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

int add_word(WordCount **wclist, const char *word) {
    /* If word is present in word_counts list, increment the count.
       Otherwise append a new element with count 1.
       Returns 0 if no errors are encountered in the body of
       this function; 1 otherwise.
     */
    if (wclist == NULL || word == NULL) { return 1; }

    WordCount *wchead = *wclist;
    WordCount *found_word = find_word(wchead, word);
    if (found_word) {
        found_word->count++;
        return 0;
    }

    WordCount *new_word = malloc(sizeof(WordCount));
    new_word->word = strdup(word);
    new_word->count = 1;
    new_word->next = NULL;

    if (wchead == NULL) {
        *wclist = new_word;
    } else {
        WordCount *curr = wchead;
        while (curr->next) {
            curr = curr->next;
        }
        curr->next = new_word;
    }
    return 0;
}

/* count words: a word is a sequence of letters. anything else is
   considered a separator.
 */
int count_words(WordCount **wclist, FILE *infile) {
    char word[MAX_WORD_LEN + 1];
    size_t len = 0;

    if (wclist == NULL || infile == NULL) { return 1; }

    for (;;) {
        int c = getc(infile);
        if (isalpha(c)) {
            if (len < sizeof word) {
                word[len] = (char)tolower(c);
            }
            len++;
        } else {
            if (len) {
                /* ignore words longer than MAX_WORD_LEN */
                if (len < sizeof word) {
                    word[len] = '\0';
                    add_word(wclist, word);
                }
                len = 0;
            }
            if (c == EOF)
                break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    WordCount *word_counts = NULL;
    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "missing filename\n");
        return 1;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        FILE *infile = fopen(argv[i], "r");
        if (infile == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "cannot open %s: %s\n", argv[i], strerror(errno));
        } else {
            count_words(&word_counts, infile);
            fclose(infile);
        }
    }
    list_words(word_counts);
    free_words(&word_counts);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How is my code adding the same char pointer`char *word`?  Sorry I'm a beginner.  I'm assuming that `fgetc` is advancing on the file content.

Thanks I didn't know about `char` not being able to detect EOF.

I'll fix the sentinel thing, I just thought writing something in the init would be better than keeping it `NULL`.

I'll add some error checks too.

Comment: Oh wait, in my `add_word` function, I should change the parameter `char *word` to `char **word`, right? Or else your suggestion.

Comment: You read every word into the allocated buffer pointed to by `word` and you set `new->word = word;` so every list node points to the same block of memory, which gets modified as you read the next word.  I posted a modified version for you to study.